# Compare two different dimensions dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2, I want to compare both dataframes and the result is saved in df3 as shown below

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_excel('Original.xlsx')
df2=pd.read_excel('Changed.xlsx')
```

df1

[image]

df2

[image]

I want output like this

[image]

Comment: 1. Please provide example data 2. What do you mean by "compare"?  Please provide df3 in addition to df1, df2

Comment: df2 comes from the df1, df2 is a modified version of df1 which contains Additional rows and columns. in the df3 I would like to mark as red-colored added rows and columns which are not available in df1.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to understand, and I think you should use code blocks to display df1, df2 and df3.

From my point of view, maybe you can use **df.filter()** and **df.concat()** to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

pivot both dataframe

```
df1_pv = df1.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Col', values='Val', aggfunc=max).reset_index()
df2_pv = df2.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Col', values='Val', aggfunc=max).reset_index()
```

It results in the same columns structure: ID, Col, Val
and it could compare changes.

```
new_id = df2_pv[~df2_pv['ID'].isin(df1_pv['ID'])] 
new_col = df2_pv[~df2_pv['Col'].isin(df1_pv['Col'])] 
val_change = pd.merge(df1_pv, df2_pv, on=['ID', 'Col'], suffixes=('_1', '_2')).query('`Val_1` != `Val_2`')
```